# How can I convert this C++ code into C code?

Tags: c++, c

I'm having hard time figuring out how to convert a simple C program.  I can't find alternatives for variables like `vector<char>`. How will it be used in C? and include `<bits/stdc++.h>`?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string remVowel(string str)
{
    vector<char> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',
    'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(),
            str[i]) != vowels.end())
        {
            str = str.replace(i, 1, "");
            i -= 2;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(){
    fstream newfile;
    newfile.open("input.txt",ios::in);
    if (newfile.is_open()){   
        string tp;
        while(getline(newfile, tp)){   
            tp = remVowel(tp);
            fstream newfile1;
            newfile1.open("output.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
            if(newfile1.is_open())
            {
                newfile1<<tp<<"\n";
                newfile1.close();
            }
        }
        newfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no simple way of doing that. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: `vector`? Write a list. `replace`? Write it yourself. `frstream` can be emulated using `FILE`.

Comment: Aside: I'd use `remove_if` instead of a loop and `string::replace` in the C++

Comment: You have a fixed-size vector, which means it could have used `std::array` in C++, and you'd use ... a raw array in C

Comment: The C++ `std::string` is _roughly_ a `char` buf and a `size_t` length. You need to decide how to handle its size/allocation yourself manually though.

Comment: @haider Well, users who don't bother getting to know the site before asking a question tend to have a bad time. To avoid the same thing happening in the future, I'd recommend a detailed reading of [ask].

Comment: @dandan78 thats not fair i did't asked a wrong question

Comment: The question you asked is far too broad.  You need to make an attempt, then if you have problems come back with a *specific* question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not trivial (in brief: well, take the algorithm and implement it in C). This program, however, is not very complicated (and it's not very efficient, and I greatly suspect, it's incorrect).

What it does is:

1. It opens a file "input.txt" for reading. Ok, in C, you have `fopen()` for it.
2. From every line found in input.txt, it removes vowels from the line. That's what `remVowel()` does, for instance `remVowel("Hi there! Are you ok?")` would return `"H thr! r y k?"`. (It does so quadratically, i.e. in an ineffective way, as a side note.)
3. Then `main()` writes all those devoweled strings into output.txt.

And that's it.